# Abrir link externo no Windows Media Player

Tags: html, html5, link, vídeo, reprodutor-de-video

Tenho uma página HTML offline que contem um link para um video `MP4`, gostaria que quando se carregasse nesse link, abrisse o Media Player ou outro software que tenha instalado e predefinido no computador para reprodução do video, é possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa usar o `file:///` (sim, são três barras), se você quiser conectar-se a arquivos locais.

```
<a href="file:///C:\Programas\meu_arquivo.mw"> Link 1 </a>
<a href="file:///C:\Videos\meuo_utro_arquivo.mp4"> Link 2 </a>
```

**Os links não vão abrir os arquivos em seus aplicativos locais automaticamente.**

Isso acontece por razões de segurança. Se ele for aberto, ele irá apenas abrir no navegador. Se o seu navegador conseguir exibir o arquivo, ele vai. Se o navegador não conseguir, ele provavelmente irá perguntar se você quer baixá-lo. Alguns navegadores, como versões modernas do Chrome, podem até mesmo se recusar a passar do protocolo http para o protocolo de arquivo.

**Os arquivos continuarão a abrir no seu browser, e isto é bom!**

Seu navegador irá responder a esses arquivos da mesma forma que ele responderá à arquivos em qualquer lugar na internet. Esses arquivos **não irão** abrir no seu aplicativo padrão (por exemplo, Word, WMP ou outro browser), e você **não conseguirá** fazer nada do tipo pedir ao Windows Explorer para abrir o local do arquivo.

**É um dos pontos mais importantes sobre navegação segura na web.**

> Sites em seu navegador não podem interagir com o seu sistema
>   operacional muito bem. **Se o seu site poderia dizer para
>   meu_video.mp4 abrir em wmplayer.exe, um site mal-intencionado também
>   poderia dizer para abrir virus.bat em cmd.exe.** Ou pode simplesmente
>   dizer ao seu PC para executar alguns arquivos uninstall.exe, ou para
>   abrir explorador de arquivos um milhão de vezes.

Talvez isso não seja conveniente para você, mas HTML e seguranças de navegadores não foram realmente concebidos para o que você está tentando fazer. Se você quer muito fazer esse processo, considere escrever um aplicativo de desktop.

Espero ter esclarecido, boa sorte.